# usb dropped from 16gb to 8gb, diskpart seems not to work

Tags: usb, diskpart

I have an 16gb usb that "dropped" to 8gb. I have tried to use diskpart but that didn't fix the problem. One reason may be that I haven't used diskpart before so I have just read a little about it through:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465

I selected the drive and did CLEAR ALL and then tried to reformat it in windows by right-clicking on the drive.

I wounder which commands I shall use on this one. Do I need to do something other then CLEAR ALL or maybe I should do the procedure completely different.

Other suggestions on solutions?

//I think that installing Linux Mint were the latest thing a did with the usb before it "lost" space. I don't remeber if I used unetbootin or another software.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had similar problems (usually with reformatting live USBs) I have used [this](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/219693/unable-to-format-usb-stick-to-full-capacity/) forum thread. romrunning's response solved my issues. The following steps are his instructions:

1. Type "DISKPART" from the Command Prompt (accessible by clicking
   on Start and then typing "cmd" into the open field); you will then
   see the following prompt: DISKPART>
2. Type "LIST DISK" to see what number your USB drive is listed as.
3. Type "SELECT DISK 2" (if your USB is disk 2; replace # with your
   disk #); Diskpart will confirm that "Disk 2 is now the select disk."
4. Type "SELECT PARTITION 1" (this command selects what should be
   the only partition on your USB drive, the small one that you want to
   delete to get back the larger, full partition size). Diskpart will
   confirm with "Partition 1 is now the selected partition."
5. Type "DELETE PARTITION". This will delete the old partition.
   There are no warning prompts if you have existing data - make sure
   you have copied everything off before doing this!
6. Type "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY" to create a new, full-size
   partition. Diskpart will confirm with message of "Diskpart succeeded
   in creating the specified partition." You can type in "LIST
   PARTITION" to confirm the new, full-size.
7. Type "EXIT" to leave Diskpart. You can now format your USB drive
   by using the standard Windows formatting process.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe how to solve a problem. Links are useful but they can become dead/broken.

Comment: Tried to do what you said but didn't work. Firstly I couldn't SELECT PARTITION 1, it said it didn't exist. So I instead did CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY, then LIST PARTITION and it showed partition 1 7711MB. I then did SELECT PARTITION 1 and after that DELETE PARTITION. I finally did CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY. When I after that did LIST PARTITION it just showed 7711MB. EXIT and then format using windows standard formatting process did not solve my problem. My disk is still 7711MB with 1024 offset(what does that mean?) or when I sometime formatted the usb i got a size of 7712MB.

Comment: @user3216616, was there a Partition 0 of which you could delete?

Comment: @user3216616 if CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY doesn't work, try the command CLEAN. I know vembutech suggested CLEAN ALL and you said it didn't work, but I found later down in the forum thread I linked that for those who CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY did not work for, CLEAN did the job for them. Sorry our suggestions aren't working. It may also be possible that some sectors on your usb are dead...

Answer (score 0):

To recover the total storage of USB,Check whether the USB drive is getting listed in the disk management.

(i) open the command prompt execute

diskpart

(ii) To list the disk

List disk

(iii) To select the disk

Select disk 0 -This is based on the output of the previous command

(iv)To make the disk clean.This would be  earse all the data

clean all

This would take consider amount of time.Once it is finished please type exit and then press enter.

Now the drive would be listed as unallocated so you can able to get the disk size back.

Comment: Did exactly what you suggested but didn't work. I get the drive unallocated but I'm only able to set it to 7711MB. I also tried right-click on it and choose format after I had done CLEAN ALL but it said it couldn't format the drive.                                                               What do you mean with:"Now the drive would be listed as unallocated so you can able to get the disk size back." Do you mean I get this by just format it?